# Inconsistent image viewing experience

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, color-spaces, srgb, saturation

I post-processed a RAW photo in Photoshop in 16bit in the ProPhoto color space and lastly exported it to an 8bit sRGB JPEG image.

Now the funny thing is that I experience different results depending on where I view the image. I use Windows 10. Photos, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Photoshop show different results.

In Photoshop and Firefox the JPEG looks like it should look - but in Photos and Internet Explorer it looks heavily over-saturated relative to my editing experience in Photoshop.

Why is that?

I am concerned that my image is not displayed consistently across software or devices. I know there is some display variation due to missing calibration, device fidelity and ambient light, but not this extreme.

Note that I am using a calibrated wide-gamut EIZO monitor (calibrated using Color Navigator and the Datacolor Spyder 5 Pro with the Photography preset).

[image: Boat]

And a comparison between Firefox and Edge rendering:

[image: Firefox (left) vs Edge (right)]

Comment: I have one wide monitor and one narrow gamut, and I have never gotten consistent results with the wide calibrated to wide, for reasons unclear (both NEC, both using SpectraView II and NEC colorimeter). I do get consistent results when calibrated to sRGB.  I believe the issue is in the browsers, despite supposedly being color managed. I, as you, found Firefox and Adobe display fine. While hardly an answer, if you are curious, try calibrating it as sRGB; it's easy to switch back. That's not an answer of course; I hope someone offers a real answer.

Comment: @Linwood How can you expect the narrow gamut monitor to display all of the colors that can be displayed by the wide gamut monitor? If the image contains colors that are outside the gamut of one but inside the gamut of the other the only way to get consistent results is to limit the wider gamut device to the capabilities of the narrower gamut device and then use the same method for translating out of gamut colors on both devices.

Comment: Michael, you misunderstand -- when I calibrate the wide to wide, normal sRGB files shown in most browsers just display wrongly. They already have a lesser color space,  but they are grossly too warm. Viewed in Lightroom or Photoshop they look fine, in firefox (if I recall) it looks fine, but Chrome it looked awful.  What I expected was that (say) AdobeRGB images would look more rich on the wide monitor side by side with narrow.  I did not expect sRGB images to be wildly different.

Comment: If I browse to my photo above (the boat in the sunset) in both Edge and Firefox it looks OK in Firefox and completely over-saturated in Edge. It's the same as if I open local image with Windows Photos - which also crazily over-saturates the image. Is it an interaction between my wide-gamut monitor, color calibration and non-color-managed software, I wonder.

Comment: I updated my post and added a side-by-side comparison image.

Comment: With a wide-gamut display, you'd expect any app that doesn't use your monitor profile properly to look over-saturated. Do you get the same results with a random picture you pull from the internet?

Comment: @MarkRansom It appears not! So yes, there might be something I'm doing wrong when exporting the images from PS.

Comment: It could just be bugs in the applications that are triggered by your exported image having a color profile. Try finding an application that can remove the color profile tag from your JPEG and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: If I export without integrated color profile then even Firefox shows the over-saturated rendering. Only if I include the color profile can (some) software show it correctly. Why on earth do I have to include a color profile for this to work. It hasn't been a problem in the past. (Side note: I had been using Save As in Photoshop rather than Export As, which I understand is the new way one should save for the web; but it doesn't look like it had any effect on this issue anyway).

Comment: Save as is bad unless you get everything right first; export (and actually the legacy save-for-web) is usually a better choice to make sure you get the right settings. I'm going to be very surprised if you find settings that look right in all the programs mentioned on a wide gamut monitor; if you do, please post the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that?

Colour management fully depends on the software as of January 2017. There is no way of enforcing it no matter how recent the OS is.

[Related question about Edge on MS site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie_other-windows_other/colour-management-non-existent-browsing-with/f8044e1b-6c53-4d7f-8a1c-d3a306d331ed) - with no answers from MS.

You should research each software to see if it supports colour management (Adobe's software does even if it is not ideal). [Firefox is not perfect without manipulation either](http://cameratico.com/guides/firefox-color-management/).

Answer (score 0):

"Oversaturated" to me sounds like the JPG file is exported as CMYK. Take a look if it is not the case.

Also it could be the case your IE is an old version. Some programs do not support some versions of the profiles.

Comment: I checked and it is an sRGB image and not exported as CMYK. I've also noticed the effect with several images.

Comment: Hum. Try to publish one image se we can take a look then.

Comment: Take a look at my question above - I already posted an image. :-)

Comment: Oh I meant side by side with the two programs you have. I see the image simmilar in my IE.

Comment: I updated my post and added a side-by-side comparison image.

Comment: You can also test by opening the original image in Edge and Firefox and compare. Do they look the same? They don't on my machine.

Comment: On this computer I am using Ie11, and they look simmilar, not as saturated as your example. Probably is a buggy implementation on Edge.